# Strange error in Latex with curly brackets

Tags: equations, errors

I cannot solve this problem. I write:

```
$[i\delta, 1/2\sqrt{3}+i(1+2\delta)/2}]$ and $[i(1+\delta), 1/2\sqrt{3}+i(1+2\delta)/2]$
```

and overleaf tells me:

```
 Extra }, or forgotten $.

l.210 ...ts $[i\delta, 1/2\sqrt{3}+i(1+2\delta)/2}
                                                  ]$ and $[i(1+\delta), 1/2\...
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

What is wrong with the text? It appears completely fine to me..

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Your first formula ends with `.../2}]`. Remove this last brace.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An unwated closing curly brace was placed at end of first math, part i.e., `$[i\delta, 1/2\sqrt{3}+i(1+2\delta)/2`}`]$`, which doesn't have matching opening brace, please remove it then try the same...